# Postgres VACUUM on replica

Tags: database, postgresql

When my postgres has both master and replica nodes, will the replica node do the same after the master node does an auto vacuum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any data modification on the primary server (with the exception of hint bits, which are an optimization that does not influence the effective state of the database) is written to WAL, replicated and replayed on the standby server. That applies to `VACUUM` as well; consequently, an autovacuum run on the primary is also an autovacuum run on the standby.